# GPIO Output Backwards

Tags: gpio, python

I have two scripts.  One turns a relay on, the other off.

As you can see bellow, lightson.py sets `GPIO` pin 17 to `HIGH` and lightsoff.py sets `GPIO` pin 17 to `LOW`.  High should be on and low off.  But to turn the light on I have to run lightsoff.py (LOW).  Is there a different way I should be doing this?

**LIGHTSON.PY**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def lights_on():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
    return '<img class="right" src="lightson.png" width="32" height="32">'

output = lights_on()    
f = open('/var/www/html/viv/lightsout.html', 'w')
print >> f, output
f.close()
```

**LIGHTSOFF.PY**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def lights_off():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
    return '<img class="right" src="lightsoff.png" width="32" height="32">'

output = lights_off()    
f = open('/var/www/html/viv/lightsout.html', 'w')
print >> f, output
f.close()
```

Comment: What type of relay do you have? There are 2 types - normally open and normally closed relays. If you have a normally closed relay, then sending High will open the relay and cause the light to go off, whereas if you have a normally open relay sending High means you are closing the circuit and activating the light.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, first time using one.  Sorry for the C/P but this is the name from Amazon: **DROK® 5V 2-Channel Relay Board AC 250V/DC 30V Extension Development Module with Optocoupler Protection for Arduino/DSP/ARM/ARM/MSP430**

Comment: @SaucedApples Things that turn on when they're grounded, have nearly 0 volts or simply "lower than supply"-voltage going to them, are typically referred to as "active low". The opposite is called "active high". NPN and PNP transistors are good examples of this and, apparently, so is your relay. There's absolutely nothing wrong with it but you could add an NPN transistor before the relay if you want to invert the logic. One thing, though, is that you need power to turn *off* your relay - this might a safety concern although it's not a defect as such. Are there pins and jumpers on the relay?

Comment: @jDo is there a way to fix this then or just one of those live with it things?

Comment: @jDo yes currently nothing is attached just testing scripts to control.  GND > GPIO GND, IN1 > GPIO 23, IN2 > GPIO 17, VCC > GPIO 5V

Comment: @SaucedApples Ok, I just saw the relay on Amazon. What if you move the blue jumper on the left so it's connected to VCC and GND instead? What if you remove it completely? Check if that inverts the logic. If it doesn't work, you could always add an NPN transistor before the relay that cuts the ground via GPIO instead; that'll give you "active high" as well.

Comment: @jDo if moved over it caused the RPi to not boot, if removed the relay light activates but the relay does not.  This is still when running the "off" script.

Comment: @SaucedApples *"if moved over it caused the RPi to not boot,"* This is serious. Sounds like a short circuit between power and ground. Sorry I even suggested it. I imagined that Amazon had user-proofed it a little more or that you would take the necessary precautions and measure voltages beforehand. Anyway, sorry - don't do it again without a resistor (you can connect the two via a 1 K and up resistor without risk of damaging anything).

Comment: @jDo no worries it appears fine.  Well I wont bother with adding a transistor as I am wanting to keep this relatively simply (It's going to control various elements in a vivarium) so it's easier to swap the use of `HIGH` and `LOW` than it is to add more hardware.  Thank you.

Comment: @SaucedApples *"This is still when running the "off" script"* If you actually *had* successfully inverted the logic, wouldn't you need to run the "on script" (gpio HIGH) to turn on the relay? Try removing the jumper completely and running the "on script".

Comment: Yes.  What I meant was to turn on the replay after removing the jumper was to run the off script.

Comment: @SaucedApples Ok. If the relays are indeed "normally closed" as Phil B suggested, then it might be a little annoying that it'll turn on the lights when you turn off the raspi. You could add a voltage divider from 5v to relay input that would act as a pull up resistor and keep it off when the raspi is off... Or just see it as *"one of those live with it things"* :)

Comment: @jDo Once the project is finished and tested, as it will control my snakes heat source and various other elements, it will only be powered off when I suffer a powercut.  So in this instance, whilst frustrating I can live with it as it causes no issue other than swapping out high and low.  Can you post this as an answer as I asked if code needed changing and it didn't.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @SaucedApples Cool, then it won't be an issue. And you're welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Phil B mentioned in the comments, there are two types of relays: normally open and normally closed. Open means "connection broken" and closed means the opposite. Adding to that, there are two "trigger" types: active high and active low. Active high means that writing a logical high activates the thing  (akin to NPN/PNP transistors).

It seems [OP's relay module](http://www.amazon.co.uk/2-Channel-Extension-Development-Optocoupler-Protection/dp/B00J4FTWO2) is normally open and active low. See the picture below for the explanation of why it's active low in this case.

[image: Active low relay module]

Thus, the python code is working fine, the relay is working, nothing's broken but it just works with a counter-intuitive logic.

Beware that there might be safety issues associated with normally closed relays since they will turn on if the controlling circuit is removed; i.e. don't use normally closed relays for your boiler/water heater/nuclear reactor.

To invert the logic, one can turn on/off the relay by cutting it's ground connection using a transistor + flyback diode instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 terminals on each relay. Keep the connection going to the center terminal. Move the other connection on the relay to the other (unused) terminal.

Comment: Did you see that OP is working with [this relay module](http://www.amazon.co.uk/2-Channel-Extension-Development-Optocoupler-Protection/dp/B00J4FTWO2)? It might support both active high and active low but I'm not sure

Comment: These relays are active high only, which means a high from the gpio will cause the relay to energize.

Comment: I am going to downvote this as it appears you have not fully read the question and comments.  EDIT: Forgot I'm not on SO so don't have enough rep.

Comment: *"These relays are active high only"* I think that's unlikely or flat out wrong since OP has to write a LOW to energize the relays. You can't both be right; I know that much :)

Comment: I think OP is not saying the relay energizes with a low. I think he is saying the light comes on with a low. If I  am incorrect then I apologize for the confusion. I use these relays all the time and have never come across this problem before. A low has always energized the relays.

Comment: @GarnettHaines Ok, I thought/think that OP has to write a GPIO LOW to close the relay. I think the confusion arises from the fact that I say "relay" even though I mean the entire relay *module* which consists of a relay, a transistor, a zener diode, two resistors, an LED and an opto-coupler per channel. The logic is inverted several times. Anyway, sorry for contributing to the confusion

Comment: A GPIO high will always energize the relay. The fact that his lights come on with a GPIO low means the connections at the relay terminals are incorrect. We could go back and forth all day with this. Let's have him rearrange the connections and see what happens.

Comment: @GarnettHaines what connections would you suggest?

Comment: @SaucedApples. Looking from the relay side of the board. Connect the power source ( voltage from the wall plug) to the center terminal. Connect the wire going to the light to the terminal on the left. This should give you an open connection untill you run the lightson.py script which will then send a high to the relay board and energize the relay. The relay will now be making a connection between the wall plug and the light.

Comment: Thus far I have only been testing my code and that the relay unit I received was fully working.  I have a desk lamp with a broken base I can use to test after removing parts so I shall give that a try with your advice but even then the code can be corrected but instead of using NC I would be using NO?  I'd rather have backwards code and the power not going to the light...

Comment: @SaucedApples Use NO. Make no change in your code and all should be working as expected.

Comment: @SaucedApples and Garnett Haines The paint-fu is very weak in this one but as I've tried to illustrate in [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/UgM2gWw.jpg), the opto-coupler is grounded via the GPIO input. As far as I can see, that *has* to mean that it's active low (unless there's some way of going around the opto-coupler entirely). Just ignore "COLL", "EMIT", and "BASE"

Comment: @jDo you are 100% correct, my bad. So the solution is to wire the relay contacts as follows. AC from the wall to the center terminal and connection to the lamp to the NO terminal. Then reverse the logic in the scripts so that Lightson is low and Lightsoff is high.

Comment: @GarnettHaines Cool cool. Yeah, I guess OP is stuck with active low until he/she buys another relay or adds an NPN transistor before the GPIO input pin. I might update the answer with an ugly paint abomination so everybody can see the hardware side of "active low"

Comment: @jDo. Google idea with the answer update. Someday I will learn how to add attachments which will make explaining things easier.

Comment: @GarnettHaines this is an odd one.  The relay is working correctly with the right high and low in the right files now the lamp is attached.  apart from turning it on during boot without it being told to, kinda annoying

Comment: You could have the Pi run the Lightsoff.py file directly after bootup. This requires making the file executable and modifying the cron file. This is not my expertise so many you could get googling Raspberry Pi cron and Raspberry Pi how to make a file excitable.

Comment: @SaucedApples Type `sudo crontab -e` and then, in the bottom of the file, add `@reboot /usr/bin/python /full/path/to/your_script.py`. `CTRL+O` and Enter to save, `CTRL+X` to exit. Then, `sudo chmod +x your_script.py` to make it executable. It should now run as root at reboot.